# Going from camera-centric coordinates to pattern-centric coordinates

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I currently have a camera alignment model set in camera as origin coordinates:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN3xY.png

and, since the camera was stationary I'm trying to convert the system to a pattern-fixed model

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAcK0.png

Matlab is nice enough to show it to me but alas there I've found no way to extract the data unless it's on a fixed-camera model. It should be a simple matter of applying the inverse of the translation and the rotation to change between systems but unfortunately this is not working and I can't see why.

```
oldpoint = [0 0 0 1]';

translation = ([1 0  0 18.1043121043; 0 1 0 31.092351038; 0 0 1 -80.0610295707; 0 0 0 1]);
rotation = [eul2rotm([0.0957937074  -0.0234017529   -0.037084526]) zeros(3,1); 0 0 0 1];


newpoint = translation * point;

newpoint = rotation * newpoint;
```

I've tried several different alternatives to this but thus far none aproximate the coordinates I'm trying to get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things were going wrong, matlab was not using euler angles and Z needed to be inverted.

```
clc;
clear;
%%
oldpoint = [0 0 0 1]';

newpoints = zeros(13,4);

i = 1;
while( i<= length(translations) )
    trans = translations(i,:);
    rota = rotations(i,:);

    display(trans);
    display(rota);

    translation = ([1 0  0 -trans(1); 0 1 0 -trans(2); 0 0 1 trans(3); 0 0 0 1]);
    rotation = [rotationVectorToMatrix([-rota(1) -rota(2) -rota(3)]) zeros(3,1); 0 0 0 1];

    newpoint = translation  * oldpoint;
    newpoint = rotation * newpoint;

    newpoints(i,:) = newpoint;
    i = i + 1;
end
```